# How to update IntelliJ Idea 11 RC to final?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ Idea 11 RC keeps saying that there is an update available but doesn't offer to install it. "Install this update" button is missing. How to fix this? When there was beta-to-RC update, the button to install was there. If I use "Help | Check for Updates" I either get a connection failure message or the same "Update Info" window without an option to install.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install the final version by itself and simply migrate your settings over.  It will prompt you to migrate your settings from a previous installation.